# Reload div with script tag inside

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a page where I want to reload the content of a div with a script tag inside. The code I use to reload this div works almost fine except that the script tag inside the div is stripped out after I reload the div.

In the following code, I have tried to explain my situation

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()); ?>
  <script>
    document.write("Script");
  </script>
</div>

<a onclick="reloadDiv();">Reload div</a>

<script>
  function reloadDiv(){
    $("#myDiv").load(location.href+" #myDiv");
  }
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So when I press Reload div the date updates but the script disappears

The code I use on my site is different but has the same principle. On my site, I use PHP to add an ID from a database so my script has to be in that div.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the whole content of your div when the load call returns. You should move your script tag somewhere else, e.g. in the head tag of your document.